# How to Call command line from TestCase in Laravel 5

Tags: unit-testing, command-line, laravel-5, laravel-testing

I am developing an application in Laravel 5, I have a test file which extends from `TestCase.php`, I need to call the `phpcs` command in my file

```
 class MyTest extends TestCase {

    public function testFunction()
    {
        //here I need to call the phpcs command                  
     }
  }
```

In  te examples here http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/testing I just found the `this->call` function, which I don't think is the proper choice for me, since it is returning a `response` object, what is the right way to do it? which Class and functions should I use to to run a command-line inside this class I also need to have the result of the command in a variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't Laravel has something built in for calling the command line. However it doesn't really need to because you can simply use the [`exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) function. Basically something like this:

```
public function testFunction()
{
    exec('phpcs', $output);
    echo $output[0]; // output line 1
}
```

As second argument you can pass a variable that will contain every line of the output as an array. The `exec()` function itself returns the last line from the output as string. (Especially useful when running single line commands like `php -v`)

Comment: thanks it seems working, but for the second part of my  question , I need to have the result of this command (the output in the stdout) in a variable, how can I get this done?

Comment: Sorry, didn't read that. See the updated answer and the official documentation as well.

Comment: It does not hide ProgressBar output. otherwise it is fine.